# Combining Persistent and IO

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying to recurse through a directory, processing files and storing the results in a database, but I'm running into a problem.

A simplified example of what I'm trying to do would look like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes, TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies, OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, FlexibleContexts #-}
import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.Sqlite
import Database.Persist.TH
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.Directory (canonicalizePath, getDirectoryContents, doesDirectoryExist, doesFileExist)
import System.FilePath (combine, takeExtension)
import Control.Monad (filterM, mapM_)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistUpperCase|
File                                                       
  path String
  deriving (Show)
|]
main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  path <- canonicalizePath $ head args
  runSqlite "files.sqlite" $ do
    runMigration migrateAll
    liftIO $ processDirectory path
    return ()

processDirectory path = files >>= mapM_ processFile >>
                        directories >>= mapM_ processDirectory
  where contents  = getDirectoryContents path >>=
                    return . map (combine path) . filter (`notElem` [".", ".."]) 
        directories = contents >>= filterM doesDirectoryExist
        files = contents >>= filterM doesFileExist

processFile path = insert $ File path
```

The above does not compile however, instead resulting in:

```
No instance for (PersistStore IO)
      arising from a use of `processFile'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (PersistStore IO)
    In the first argument of `mapM_', namely `processFile'
    In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `mapM_ processFile'
    In the first argument of `(>>)', namely
      `files >>= mapM_ processFile'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

This makes sense to me, since processFile is just a call to insert, which part of the PersistStore monad (right?) not IO.  I think what I need is a monad transformer, but at this point I'm running into a brick wall, which perhaps means I'm barking up the wrong tree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The one thing you do **not** want enclosed by *liftIO* is the database action, so you need to rearrange the code to leave *processFile* outside of it.

About the simplest change to your code which will make it compile is the following.  I will leave it to you to tidy it up so that it is clearer what is going on!

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes, TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies, OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, FlexibleContexts #-}
import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.Sqlite
import Database.Persist.TH
import System.Environment (getArgs)
import System.Directory (canonicalizePath, getDirectoryContents, doesDirectoryExist, doesFileExist)
import System.FilePath (combine, takeExtension)
import Control.Monad (filterM, mapM_)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistUpperCase|
File                                                       
  path String
  deriving (Show)
|]
main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  path <- canonicalizePath $ head args
  runSqlite "files.sqlite" $ do
    runMigration migrateAll
    processDirectory path
    return ()

processDirectory path = liftIO files >>= mapM_ processFile >>
                        liftIO directories >>= mapM_ processDirectory
  where contents  = getDirectoryContents path >>=
                    return . map (combine path) . filter (`notElem` [".", ".."])  
        directories = contents >>= filterM doesDirectoryExist
        files = contents >>= filterM doesFileExist

processFile path = insert $ File path
```

Comment: Ah, yes that should have been obvious once I found liftIO and what it did.  I think I had been staring at it too long.  Thanks!